# css styles are not applying in IE6.0

Tags: css, cross-browser

i am creating a button using Jquery in myPage.jsp. it is working fine in Mozilla firefox but the css are not getting applied in IE . **ui-corner-all** is not applying in IE. the corner are not rounded.

```
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
 <input type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all  ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" value="button"></input> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Seriously consider not having to support IE6...really if you can convince the powers that be.  IE6 only styles can be put inside: `<!--[if IE 6]> <style> ... </style><![endif]-->`

Comment: Someone forgot to research browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 6 doesn't support `border-radius` CSS attribute. Take a look at [CSS Rounded Corners In All Browsers (With No Images)](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers) blog post.

Comment: Definitely helpful (so upvoting) but worth supporting Yzmir's comment in the original post that it's even better to not support IE6. Or at least use progressive enhancement... who "needs" border radius?